# Get local time from UTC datetime in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, utc, localtime

Does AS3 have a way of converting a datetime variable into local time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Some date string you got from somewhere
var dateStr:String = "Sun Sep 25 22:30:33 GMT+0600 2011";
var date:Date = new Date(dateStr);

//Use date.toLocaleString() to get a local time string and create a new date from it
var localDate:Date = new Date(date.toLocaleString());
trace(localDate);'
```

Here's a link to date.toLocaleString() from Adobe

[date.toLocaleString() Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#toLocaleString%28%29)

Comment: Ah, so I can pass in a time string to Date(). Thanks.

Comment: There's no point creating a new Date object from date.toLocaleString(). That only creates a new Date object identical to the first. Just 'trace(date)' to see.